# Excel to find out Windows version in network

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to create a macro, which would find out Windows version in my network (cca 200 PC) using Excel? I saw on many website in information (windows+web browser+ip) but in Excel. I don't know.

Comment: What information do you know about the other PCs on the network ? Do you know their IP, MAC address, machine names, etc ?

Answer (score -1):

`Application.OperatingSystem` returns the name and version number of the current operating system — for example, "Windows (32-bit) 4.00" or "Macintosh 7.00". It is a read-only string.

This example displays the name of the operating system.

`MsgBox "Microsoft Excel is using " & Application.OperatingSystem`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-operatingsystem-property-excel

Comment: Yea... "current operating system" on my PC,but i need 200x PC (all IP already in excel) in network. 200x IP ping and find out Windows version and write to Excel.  Input : PCName(IP) - Out: WindowsVersion

Comment: Do you mean you would like to execute "Application.OperatingSystem" on 200 PCs remotely?

Comment: Yes or another command...  i have macro with ping all PC in list:  A1 - PCNAME(IP) --> B1 - ms/ping,it works.  Now i need "ping" windows version and puts in to excel "B1". :)

Comment: If you have the right to do it then you could use the script from this site https://www.devhut.net/2016/09/24/vba-determine-the-installed-os/